# Ignoring first key pressed when waking up

Tags: unity

As far as remember Mac OS X ignores the first key pressed when computer is sleeping while Ubuntu passes it to password field so I have to delete the first character. Is there a way to replicate Mac OS X behaviour on Ubuntu with Unity?

Comment: @DavidCole: I disagree with the close vote - the question is "How can I make Ubuntu exhibit Mac-like behavior", which, misguided as it is, IS about Ubuntu.

Comment: Voted to keep open...

Answer (score 2):

Wake your computer up with the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, or the first character of your password.

Comment: While yes this does work, there should also be a way to make Ubuntu pass the first key that is pressed after reboot. This would work as a temporary work-around though.

Comment: @DavidCole: I strongly disagree with any change that would make Ubuntu drop/ignore a character I type, or ignore the Shift key. Other than this SINGLE use case (Former Mac user wants Mac bug behavior), what good is it?

Comment: The OP has a question about Ubuntu, instead of making a work-around, we should try to solve it. I am currently not on my Linux machine, so I cannot look around, but if there is a will there is a way

Comment: @DavidCole: Really? If an other OP asked "Ubuntu can't run Windows viruses, please fix",  would you suggest working on that? The Mac behavior referred to is a BUG. We should not port BUGS.

Comment: Oh! Sorry! I thought that this Mac OS X ability was an actual function of Mac. Didn't realize that it was a bug

Comment: @waltinator Are you sure it's a bug? I find it very convenient to wake up the PC by hitting space and always thought it was intentional

Comment: I think that any time the computer ignores what I type, it's a problem. If you cannot retrain to use Shift, change your password so that the first character is a Space (`man passwd` says one can use any character EXCEPT "`the system default erase or kill characters`", and Space is neither).